# How to git the most recent snapshot of a google code repository (not a clone)

Tags: git, testing

So I'm working with code.google.com for the first time, and with git for the first time.

I understand how to create a clone for development purposes, but how do I just git the most recent snapshot (HEAD?) of a repository?

The use case here is:  I'm working on one system for development, and I build another system for testing (or I have other people doing testing).  I just want to wget the most recent committed files on this new system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then just clone only one revision with `git clone`. Like this:

```
git clone --depth 1 <clone URL>
```

`--depth 1` tells git to fetch only `HEAD`.

From `git help clone`:

```
--depth <depth>
           Create a shallow clone with a history truncated to the specified number of revisions.
...
```

Comment: but isn't clone for development or checkout purposes?  Hey, I'm new at git, so I'm just asking for clarification.  From docs: "creates and checks out an initial branch that is forked from the cloned repository’s currently active branch"

Comment: @MarkSatterfield, there is no distinction whether you're cloning for developing or cloning just to build it, interface is the same. In both cases you obtaining source code, what you're going to do with it doesn't matter. It's perfectly fine to, say, clone whole repository, checkout specific tag (e.g. `0.5.0`) and build it, you can find similar instructions in documentation for some software. Automatic build systems do the same.